# Convert factor numeric variable to factor string in R

Tags: r

I have a vector of numeric:

`1 3 2 4 3 3 ...`

I want to convert it to a vector of factor, with `1 = "Good"`, `2="OK"`, `"3= "Bad"` etc.

Comment: read `help("factor")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `factor` with `levels` and `labels` specified.

```
set.seed(24)
factor(sample(1:3, 10, replace=TRUE), levels=1:3, 
                       labels= c('Good', 'OK', 'Bad'))
```

Or a variant suggested by @David Arenburg

```
factor(c('Good', 'OK', 'Bad')[sample(1:3, 10, replace=TRUE)])
```

Comment: Do you need to specify `levels` in this case? You could also do `factor(c('Good', 'OK', 'Bad')[sample(1:3, 10, replace=TRUE)])` probably.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thanks for the comment. Yes, this can be done in many ways.